# Video streaming in Apple Watch app

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, apple-watch

Is Video streaming supported in iWatch?
Can we stream videos from a camera placed in a remote location?
If a camera is recording a video, then is it possible to show the video in an iWatch output screen ?

I have an iPhone app that streams video. Can i make the same video playing happen on iWatch?

Answer (score 2):

If we really want to view "video" what we will have to do is to chop up the video into images, leaving a gap between them, and then sequentially display them on the Apple Watch.
This is the answer I got after some surfing.

Comment: My requirement is to render live AVCapsturesession on watch. Is that possible? How?